# How to convince a customer that what he wants is a bad thing to do?

Tags: usability

For instance, customers that we're creating web sites for, request things like:

- all links should open in a new window
- put custom 'Back' button on every
  page while there is a working
  browser's equivalent
- make some part of the text blinking etc.

Of course I tell them it's wrong, but is there some nice list of bad things to have from a respected source that I can point them to?

Comment: good Q, but isn't this a duplicate? (can't find the Q though)

Comment: "make some part of the text blinking"

I Didn't realise I'd gone back in time to the 1990s... ;)

Comment: Another thought would be to show them where there are browser settings that can do some of this as perhaps they just don't know about such options in the browser software?  My firefox has a setting for new pages to open in a new windows or a new tab, which is a feature I like.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Always try and show them how it will cost them money. For example, if they are going to do something that annoys the user, they will have less traffic which will lead to less revenue.

For better or worse, dollars always speak the loudest.

Comment: `For better or worse, dollars always speak the loudest`. Exactly, and funny  :-)

Answer (score 16):

Become that respected source. Seriously: if your clients are showing reluctance to take your advice directly, compose documents that illustrate good and bad user interface design and publish it on your website. You gain three things from this:

1. You *become* more knowledgeable about the *why* of bad and good design. Having to think through something to compose it into a document is more helpful than many give it credit for.
2. If this is publicly published, you probably will get feedback about your ideas. Throw away the bad suggestions and integrate the good, and you become better at your craft.
3. You have the source for these discussions in a presentable format, yet you retain all your personal branding. If you include examples and demos of the good and bad, most people can see why you advocate for your ideas.

EDIT: epotter is dead on as far as the "buck stops here" aspect of interacting with a client. If your documents can show why irritating a user is a loss of revenue in the long run, it is unlikely you will have much push-back. On the other hand, if your personal preferences includes UI designs that *don't* help with retention... stop doing that. (I recall the days of "CSS Only, No Tables" designers before CSS had matured: they insisted on forcing their designs on clients, even though in some browsers they didn't render well. While a cause is admirable, you work for the *client* not a cause.)

Comment: +1 couldn't agree more - "you work for the client not a cause." excellent.

Comment: Well, good suggestions in an ideal world. To do it good you need to have a lot of will, time and knowledge of English grammar. And I'm short on all of those.

Comment: To be a consultant you need a lot of will, time and knowledge of your *subject* (English depends on your context; I'm likewise unlikely to get many German contracts). I know that "do the legwork" advice doesn't sell well, but battling over adversity is what leads to the biggest gains in life.

Answer (score 8):

First, don't tell them it's wrong.

They may take it personally.

Instead, understand the need they are trying to fill, then suggest alternatives that don't include the bad behavior.  Mock all the alternatives up and point out the good and bad of each one.  Let them choose.  As long as you have a good alternative, and sufficiently pointed out the faults of the bad implementation, then they generally come around to your point of view.

In other words, act like a designer.  When a customer says, "I want green text on a red background," you don't immediately tell them that 10% of the world's males cannot read that, you first need to understand why. "Well, it's Christmas," then you can suggest alternate themes to give the site a festive feel without the design error.  As long as the mockups you suggest are better than theirs then they will generally acquiesce.

**Not because they made an error, but because you saw their *real* need and improved on their idea.**

If they're adamant after that, though, do the work - don't spend your time trying to convince them the error of their design sense, it's a waste of resources.

*Educate them over the long term, but if it takes you an hour to convince them not to make a change, that's one hour you could have spent improving your relationship with customers who treat you as designers rather than web-monkeys.*

-Adam

Answer (score 6):

I've had to play a semi-sales role at time with web projects and I have to stress how important it is to keep the customer happy.

Nevertheless, I completely agree with you that you are obligated to say something in the name of giving them what they want.  I always found that the best approach is to start by agreeing with them (in principal at least).  You could say,

> "I completely agree with you that this
>   text is very important to your users. 
>   Many testers that I've worked with
>   have strongly preferred using this
>   font/graphic/color to call out
>   critical text.  Unfortunately, some
>   users associate flashing text with ads
>   and avoid it"

I find that this approach lets them know that you

1. Understand what they want
2. Appreciate their motivations and suggestions
3. Only want to help

One last word of advice, if after the gentle nudging, they don't get the point, consider doing two quick mock-ups. (their idea and yours).  If that doesn't work, then just give them what they want.  In the end, they pays the bills and if they really want an ugly site (assuming you can't afford to turn away business on aesthetic grounds) just give them the site.

Good luck and take deep breaths!

Answer (score 6):

Jakob Nielsen's Alertbox has been an invaluable source of common-sense usability advice for me for many years. Here's [something he wrote](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/9612.html) way back in 1996 that still applies today:

> The BACK feature is an absolutely
> essential safety net that gives users
> the confidence to navigate freely in
> the knowledge that they can always get
> back to firm ground. We have known
> from some of the earliest studies of
> user navigation behaviorthat BACK is
> the second-most used navigation
> feature in Web browsers (after the
> simple "click on a link to follow it"
> action). Thus, breaking the BACK
> button is no less than a usability
> catastrophe.

And here are the first two of his [Top Ten Web Design Mistakes of **1999**](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/990530.html):

> **Breaking or Slowing Down the Back Button**
>
> The Back button is the lifeline
> of the Web user and the second-most
> used navigation feature (after
> following hypertext links). Users
> happily know that they can try
> anything on the Web and always be
> saved by a click or two on Back to
> return them to familiar territory.
>
> Except, of course, for those sites
> that break Back by committing one of
> these design sins:
>
> - opening a new browser window (see mistake #2)
> - using an immediate redirect: every time the user clicks Back, the
>   browser returns to a page that bounces the user forward to the undesired location
> - prevents caching such that the Back navigation requires a fresh trip
>   to the server; all hypertext navigation should be sub-second and
>   this goes double for backtracking
>
> **Opening New Browser Windows**
>
> Opening up new browser windows is like a
> vacuum cleaner sales person who starts
> a visit by emptying an ash tray on the
> customer's carpet. Don't pollute my
> screen with any more windows, thanks
> (particularly since current operating
> systems have miserable window
> management). If I want a new window, I
> will open it myself!
>
> Designers open new browser windows on
> the theory that it keeps users on
> their site. But even disregarding the
> user-hostile message implied in taking
> over the user's machine, the strategy
> is self-defeating since it disables
> the Back button which is the normal
> way users return to previous sites.
> Users often don't notice that a new
> window has opened, especially if they
> are using a small monitor where the
> windows are maximized to fill up the
> screen. So a user who tries to return
> to the origin will be confused by a
> grayed out Back button.

These aren't crazy newfangled ideas, they're decade-old guidelines based on hard research. You'd need a really, really, **really** good excuse to repeat a decade-old mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Find examples of actual pages that do this and show them.  [Here's a good place to find some.](http://www.webpagesthatsuck.com/)

If you show them the examples, and instead of being awed by the suckyness and changing their minds, the clients say, "Yeah!  That's exactly what I want!", then make them sign a nondisclosure contract saying they'll never tell anyone who designed their web site.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to explain "why". It's not enough to tell them something is "wrong" (and in these cases, it's not so much "wrong" as it is a "bad idea")

Most people respond well to logic and reason. If you can make a reasoned argument for why doing something a certain way is a bad idea, they'll usually bow down to your experience and knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

useit.com is an excellent resource for usability arguments

but you're probably wasting your time. Either do it their way ("the customer is always right") or walk away - arguing is unlikely to improve the situation *unless* you can demonstrate a significant monetary gain from not doing it their way, which you probably cannot do given the issues you listed.

if your name will be on the site, i'd politely walk away

Comment: useit.com was my first pick, but that site (although has a good content) desperately needs to be redesigned itself.

Comment: ditto.  For a site that promotes usability, it is terribly ugly and difficult to read.  It would be easier to respect Nielsen's ideas if he applied them to his own site.

Comment: @[sneg]: @[Robert Claypool]: looks ok to me - not web 2.0 fancy, but easily readable

Answer (score 2):

Show them some articles on sites like http://useit.com which has some empirical studies on how adherence to web standard practices increases usability and so therefore user satisfaction and so therefore profit.

Answer (score 2):

Ask them what results they're after. "Have all links open in a new window" is a statement of solution. Solutions are **your** job, the client's job is to state objectives.

Start with this: "Oh, you'd like links to open in a new window. Tell me more about why you want that - I'd like to explore with you whether there are alternate ways of getting the same results."

Perhaps continue with this: "Also, I might point your attention to *other* consequences of opening all links in a new window - consequences you might not have considered, and which perhaps you wouldn't like."

Suggested reading: [Dale Emery's articles](http://dhemery.com/articles/resistance_as_a_resource/) on resistance.

Comment: Usually they ask something like that because that's how contact person feels about it.

Answer (score 1):

At the simplest, try to explain them each of it in a user understandable manner.
e.g. Blinking text is an old style thing not supported by all browsers
Not sure why "back" can be a problem. But put your viewpoint.

Comment: A custom Back link often breaks the browser's Back button, which is a Cardinal Sin in web design.  Check out the book "Don't Make Me Think".

Answer (score 1):

It's always convincing if you demonstrate to the user that his design is unconventional or wrong by showing a list of very well known websites that he would "respect" and pointing out how they don't do X. Your customer will probably want his site to be *like* the big players' web sites.

If he still insists that his weird design makes sense you could say: "yes, I agree that sounds like a good idea in theory, but the fact is that users are simply unaccustomed to X and would walk away from your website if it diverges too widely from the standard way of doing things".

IOW, when all else fails, use fear.

Comment: Big players are sometimes have blunders themselves. And usually customer looks at a site of his biggest competitor in their field of business, which doesn't mean their web site is any good at all.

Answer (score 1):

*You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make it drink.*

With customers (of any type), the best you can do is inform them of their choices, and why they are not the best ones and then leave it. If it's really bad, require sign-off stating that they find that design acceptable. Do you want to be 'right' or do you want to get something into the customer's hands that works?

If it completely impedes a working solution, then (and only then) should you stand on principle, but beware you have very few (if any) of these 'stands', so use them wisely. Be prepared to walk away.

Paul.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a compelling business case NOT to do it (and I'm not sure this is the case with any of your examples) then if the customer is adamant DO IT! They are paying for it after all. They can always find someone else who will do it if you won't!

Comment: I'm putting my credentials at the bottom of their web site and I don't want to be ashamed after that.